# FAGL_ACCOUNT_ITEMS_GL_API - Need values in 3 decimal places

Tags: api, sap-erp

The Function module in SAP - FAGL_ACCOUNT_ITEMS_GL_API output's the data in 2 decimal places.
In Muscat (Oman) client uses 3 places after decimal to view amount.
How to achieve this here?

Thanks and Regards
CA. Nilesh Zambhuria

Comment: no way, if the precision of FM is less than you need, you gotta search for another FM

Answer (score 0):

SAP *always* stores the posting amounts with two decimals. If the posting currency has three decimal places (you can check in table TCURX, field CURRDEC or in transaction OY04) it will be like this:

posting amount: 1.234

but in the database will be stored like: 12.34

Similiarly if a currency has no decimal places (like HUF for example), than:

posting amount: 100

in the database: 1.00

SAP will handle this inside SAP (standard transactions, ALV lists, etc.) properly (as long as the number of decimal places was set up correctly - it is not possible to change it in a live SAP system!).

In your case the function module will give back values with two decimal places, like 12.34 But in case the currency has three decimal playes (like OMR), you have to understand it like 1.234.